# Configuring Sitecore Publishing Service to update multiple custom indexes

Tags: configuration, publishing-service, patch-configuration

I'm currently trying to set up the Sitecore Publishing Service on an instance of Sitecore 10.1 (the page for all of the downloads and instructions is [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_Module/10x/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_Module_1010.aspx))

Without the publishing service, we rely on 4 custom indexes to be updated when an item is published.

The "[Publishing Module Installation and Configuration Guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/191102938E5E4B8382110A51F41A74A2.ashx?date=20210225T114055)" states the following about custom indexes (apologies for the formatting):

> **1.3.3 Configuring Cache Clearing and Indexing**

> The Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.config is responsible for raising events to
> rebuild the search indexes and clear data caches on the target instance.
> If additional custom indexes have been created on a Sitecore instance, each index name must be
> added to the publishingservice:searchindex.rebuild setting in the IndexNames section:

```
<event name="publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild">
    <handler
type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetSearchIndexRebuildHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="RebuildTargetSearchIndex">
        <IndexNames hint="list:AddIndex">
            <index>sitecore_web_index</index>
            <customIndex>MyCustomIndex</customIndex>
        </IndexNames>
    </handler>
</event>
```

As such, I have the following in my configuration patch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetSearchIndexRebuildHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="RebuildTargetSearchIndex">
          <IndexNames hint="list:AddIndex">
            <index>sitecore_web_index</index>
            <customIndex>customindex_1</customIndex>
            <customIndex>customindex_2</customIndex>
            <customIndex>customindex_3</customIndex>
            <customIndex>customindex_4</customIndex>
          </IndexNames>
        </handler>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

The resulting output when I go to admin/ShowConfig.aspx is the following:

```
<event name="publishingservice:searchindex:rebuild" patch:source="z.Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.Patch.config">
    <handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.TargetSearchIndexRebuildHandler, Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery" method="RebuildTargetSearchIndex" patch:source="z.Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.Patch.config">
        <IndexNames hint="list:AddIndex" patch:source="z.Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.Patch.config">
           <index>sitecore_web_index</index>
           <customIndex patch:source="z.Sitecore.Publishing.Service.Delivery.Patch.config">customindex_4</customIndex>
        </IndexNames>
    </handler>
</event>
```

So it seems that the custom index declarations are overriding each other until only the last one remains.

How should I alter the configuration files so that all of the custom indexes will be updated when an item is published through the publishing service?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different tag names for each of the indexes. Otherwise Sitecore will merge them into one.

Use:

```
<customIndex1>customindex_1</customIndex1>
<customIndex2>customindex_2</customIndex2>
<customIndex3>customindex_3</customIndex3>
<customIndex4>customindex_4</customIndex4>
```

Comment: Thanks, if the other solution doesn't work I'll test this, and then if this works accept it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

A common way to separate multiple elements with the same name is to use a `desc` description attribute. This will prevent Sitecore from merging the elements and it's fairly easy to write patch expressions etc. Example:

```
<IndexNames ...>
  <index desc="sitecore_web_index">sitecore_web_index</index>
  <index desc="your_custom_index1">your_custom_index1</index>
  <index desc="your_custom_index2">your_custom_index2</index>
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and if that works accept this answer